# Function to add names to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, names

I'm have a data frame without columns:

```
df<-data.frame(v1=c(1:10), v2=seq(1, 100, length=10))
```

I want to change the header names to "X" and "Y"

I know I can do this using:

```
names(df)<-c("X","Y")
```

What I would like to do is write a function where I could pass a data frame as an argument, and place the headers with these header names.

I've tried:

```
get.names<- function(x)
    {names(x)<-c("X", "Y")}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function sets the names; you just need to return the object.

```
get.names<- function(x) {
    names(x)<-c("X", "Y")
    x
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `setNames` function

```
> setNames(data.frame(v1=c(1:10), v2=seq(1, 100, length=10)), c("X","Y"))
    X   Y
1   1   1
2   2  12
3   3  23
4   4  34
5   5  45
6   6  56
7   7  67
8   8  78
9   9  89
10 10 100
```

Comment: Yes. and if you look at the source code of `setNames` you'll see how close you are to that.

Answer (score 6):

There is an R function which already does this, although instead of modifying the data frame your environment, it returns the renamed data frame:

```
df<-`names<-`(df, new_names)
```

In fact, you are already using this function, in a roundabout way, when you call `names(df)<-` ...

---

Note that almost no functions in R modify the values they have been passed - almost all are 'functional' in style - performing the changes to a new copy and returning that.  For this reason you should expect to see and write lots of code in the form: `x=f(x)`.

---

Another technique you may find useful is the `rename` function in the `reshape` package:

```
df<-rename(df,c(v1="X", v2="Y"))
```

Which just changes the names of the specified columns.  It also works to rename names in lists and vectors!

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to side-step the internal copying with `names<-` and `df<-rename(df,c(v1="X", v2="Y"))` and `setNames` you can  use the `data.table` package

```
# some example data
library(data.table)
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
DT <- data.table(DF)
```

You can set the names of a `data.table` by reference (without copying) using `setnames`

```
setnames(DT, new = c('new_name1','newname2'))
DT
   new_name1 newname2
1:         1        1
2:         2        2
3:         3        3
4:         4        4
5:         5        5
# you can change only a subset by defining old and new
setnames(DT, old = 'new_name1', new = 'blah')
DT
        blah newname2
1:         1        1
2:         2        2
3:         3        3
4:         4        4
5:         5        5
```

If you don't want to use data.tables, you can use the `setattr` function from `data.table` package (which is very like the function of the same name in the `bit` package)

```
setattr(DF, 'names', c('oh','look'))
DF

  oh look
1  1    1
2  2    2
3  3    3
4  4    4
5  5    5

 bit::setattr(DF, 'names', c('yip','hee'))
DF
  yip hee
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
5   5   5
```